# Как посчитать сумму первых 3-х элементов в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Как посчитать с 1-3, 4-6 итд сумму элементов в массиве ?

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); нужно 1+2+3 потом 4+5+6.
```

Как по мне, то это примитивно, есть ли другой способ ?

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
        $sum += $arr[$i];
}
var_dump($arr);
print_r($sum);
?>
```

Comment: А самому попытаться? Где код?

Comment: Добавил код выше

Comment: вам же [ответили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658884/223826) уже про суммы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_sub_sum($arr, $start, $count) {
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sum += $arr[$start + $i];
    }
    return $sum;
}
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

print(get_sub_sum($arr, 0, 3)); // 1,2,3
print(get_sub_sum($arr, 3, 3)); // 4,5,6
```

Comment: про `array_chunk` и `array_sum`  не читали никогда? ;)

Comment: Про array_chunk  - нет. Не уверен, что ответ `print_r(array_map("array_sum", array_chunk(array(1,2,3,4,5,6),3)));` автору сильно помог бы разобраться в вопросе.